# PDOStatement::fetch_array()

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou com um problema em um `input` do tipo *Select* (segue o trecho abaixo). Estou usando a versão 7.0 do PHP e como SGBD o PostgreSQL. Tentei utilizar a função `pg_fetch_array` mas foi sem sucesso , alguém tem ideia do que possa estar errado?

[image: Display Error]

```
<?php
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM atividades";
    $query = $db->db->query("SELECT * FROM atividades");
?>
 <select>
          <?php 
            echo "<select name='descricao'>";
              while($cont = $query->fetch_array()) {
                echo "<option value='".$cont["id"]."'>".$cont["descricao"]."</option>";
              }
            echo "</select>";
          ?>
      </select>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este e o retorno especificado Pelo var_dump($query);

Comment: Antes de executar `$query->fetch_array()`, faça `var_dump($query)` e coloque aqui o resultado.

Comment: poste o código de conexão `$query->fetch_array(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` de um `var_dumb($cont);`

Comment: lembrando que tens que dar `$query->execute();`